# using vbscript to split a file and save it when it sees a specific character

Tags: command-line, batch-file, vbscript

I would like to use vbscript or the windows cmd.exe command line in a batch script.

My goal is this.

When a specific character in a text file is found, ie."ST", it would save all the text starting from and including when it sees the characters "ST" until it finds the next instance of ST. If it sees the next instance of "ST" then it should split the file saving the characters in the file from the first instance of "ST" with all the data up until the next "ST", of course it would not need to write the second instance of the actual characters "ST" in that first file.  If it doesn't see another instance of "ST" then it would simply copy the file as is and naming it for example, new1.txt.  If it finds several instances of ST then each 
file should be called new1.txt, new2.txt, new3.txt, new4.txt and so forth.

Ex.
Say you have a text file named output.txt, and it contains the following..

```
ST 123 Abcrfg 78
ST !! 143 Bng 678
```

Then I would like to use vbscript of the windows command line to read the file called output.txt and do the following...

Write a file called new1.txt that would contain the data:

```
ST 123 Abcrfg 78
```

Then I would like to see another file created called new2.txt that would contain..

```
ST !! 143 Bng 678
```

Any assistance with this would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: welcome to SO. Please try to ask a specific question. What have you tried? what problems have you had?

Comment: What happens if ST is in the middle of a line? What if ST appears within a word like START?

Comment: I doesn't matter where ST is in the text file, i still need a new file to be created for every instance of ST.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplistic approach might look like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

data = Split(fso.OpenTextFile("output.txt").ReadAll, "ST")
For i = 1 To UBound(data)
  fso.OpenTextFile("new" & i & ".txt", 2, True).Write "ST" & data(i)
Next
```

This will read the entire input file, split the text on every occurrence of "ST" and write each fragment to a separate file. The first fragment (text before the first occurrence of "ST") will be ignored.

Note that this is only suitable for small files (i.e. files that will easily fit in the computer's RAM. For larger files you'll have to parse the file.